# How to perform a swipe with 'duration' using sendevent and adb

Tags: android, adb

I'm using the code above to simulate a 'swipe' using sendevent:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 300 ;First position X
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 600 ;First position Y
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 48 5
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 58 50
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0

sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 53 300  ;Second position X
sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 54 400  ;Second position Y
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0

sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 2 0
sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

However, it does swipe instantly without any delay.

I'm trying to figure how to specify the duration of the swipe, like you can do using adb shell input:

`input [touchscreen|touchpad|touchnavigation] swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)]`

`shell input swipe 300 400 300 200 2000`

This produces a swipe with a duration of 2 seconds.

I have tried to add a
`sleep 2` before the `;Second position` but it does result in a pause before the swipe instead of a swipe with 2 seconds of duration.

With duration I mean, the time slowly swapping from position 1 to position 2.

Comment: so @Frank any of the answers below helped to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the [sendevent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/heads/android-s-beta-4/toys/android/sendevent.c) and [input](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java) commands' source code you can clearly understand their goals; the former covers basic command line's input events whereas the latter covers more flexible and complex input scenarios.

To get an insight on how the swipe duration has been implemented (on input command) you can focus directly on the [sendSwipe](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/HEAD/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java#244) method: it sends multiple basic input events, leveraging the InputManager, in a timespan defined by the duration parameter

```
final long endTime = down + duration;
```

The function `injectMotionEvent` used by `sendSwipe` doesn't have any concept of "duration".

That said, I think the command you're looking for, as of today, doesn't exist and I believe you can still rely on console prompt like

```
input swipe 300 400 300 200 2000
```

that can be invoked after using

```
adb shell
```

Answer (score 1):

One cannot set the duration on the low level, but one can record analog input and then play it back. This permits for more flexible and complex scenarios ...because the events are countless.

---

Run `adb shell` to open a shell.

Where ...

- `getevent --help` shows all available options.
- `getevent -p` shows all recordable devices.
- `getevent -lp /dev/input/event1` shows `BTN_TOUCH` event data format.
- `getevent /dev/input/event1` logs input events for device `focaltech_ts`.
- `getevent -l /dev/input/event1` is human-readable (useless for automation).

To record:

- `cd sdcard/Download`
- `getevent /dev/input/event1 >> ./swipe.log`
- download `swipe.log` with the Android device explorer.

Where `0003` means coordinate, and `0x35` is the X-axis and `0x36` is the Y-axis:

```
0003 0035 000001a8
0003 0036 000005cb
```

---

This log can the be played back by a shell script loop, with `sendevent`.
`sendevent --help` shows the expected parameters: `DEVICE TYPE CODE VALUE`.

```
cat ./swipe.log | while read line 
do
    adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event1 $line
done
```

When delaying the execution with `sleep`, the lines with `0000 0000 00000000` might suit best.

---

Alike this one can also automate GPIO buttons, which maybe be quite specific on certain devices. [`UiObject2.swipe()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiObject2#swipe) might also just generate linear-interpolation coordinates and play them back. It generally does not matter, if they're generated or recorded - the only difference is that the one movement is perfectly straight and the other one obviously isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that sending events through `sendevent` takes some time. I made a python [script](https://gist.github.com/Luengor/653a34fc187b65052977dd76a4627b85) (You can take whatever you need from there) that interpolates points between the given ones. It also waits some time between points.

This is the lineal interpolation code:

```
def lerp(p1:tuple, p2:tuple, points:int) -> list:
    output = []
    header = [_p2 - _p1 for _p1, _p2 in zip(p1, p2)]
    for p in range(points + 1):
        percent = p / points
        output.append((p1[0] + percent * header[0], p1[1] + percent * header[1]))
    return output
```

The time problem appears when using multiples points. Using a path with 10 interpolated points with no time between them already takes 1.29 seconds and a 100 points one, 11.45.

Comment: Sorry, i had not seen your answer, I'm looking for something that could be sent directly to the console prompt.